# Help me understand the first three lines from 松任谷由実’ｓ　「甘い予感」

Tags: meaning, translation, song-lyrics, culture

> あなたの耳のむこう
>
> 夕日がきれいね
>
> 息をかけたら消えそう

Source: http://j-lyric.net/artist/a000c13/l00f5ed.html

Song on the Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9Zm8sorINQ

Translating the three lines literally

> The sun beyond your ears
>
> is so beautiful
>
> feels like my breath (out) would disappear (I might be misunderstanding or mistranslating this part. I don't know how else I would translate 息をかける)

Further down, she says

> 夏がゆく頃に恋も終わるって
>
> 誰が決めたそんなこと
>
> 私は信じない

Which makes think the season is summer. Further down, she also talks about Beach Boys playing on the radio. Which further strengthens the summer feeling.

> ふとつけたのカーラジオ
>
> 流れてクルのは　ビーチボーイズ

If the season is summer, first three lines (third line especially) sound confusing

> あなたの耳のむこう　夕日がきれいね

The setting sun beyond your ears is beautiful.

Sun beyond the ears strikes me as an odd way of putting it somehow. I wonder if it actually means something else and how does it tie up with first two lines before?

And then the third line says

> 息をかけたら消えそう

Why does she say "as if my breath would disappear" here if the season is summer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 耳の向こう looked puzzling to me too at first, but the same person is saying あなたの肩に顔を埋めた, so I think she is seeing the sun literally "beyond your ear". I don't think 耳の向こう is related to some idiom.

息をかけたら消えそう means "If I blow on it, it might disappear", where "it" refers to the sun (息をかける = "to blow on something", 息をはく = "to breathe out"). Throughout the lyrics, she is basically worrying that everything is about to go away, so I guess this line expresses her anxiety, too.

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございました。On a related note, why does she say あなたの肩に顔を埋めた色あせた空がせつなかったの。Why does she find that painful (translating 切ない as painful here)

Comment: @vadasambar I think that's simply because the sunset is the symbol of the passage of time to her.